# can svn command line commit be like tortoisesvn commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

to give a little background, i am required to perform a synch between a folder X with a svnfolder Y. Folder X is the master so after the synch folder Y contains the exact same files/folders as folder X (apart from folder Y contains a .svn folder).

After the synch i want to commit Y through the command line. I want all new files to be commited and all files that were deleted as part of the synch deleted on the SVN repo.

This can be done easily using tortoise svn by checking the include unversioned files checkbox however i can seem to do it through the command line.

Is there a flag that can be used to force the commit (similar to doing on tortoisesvn) so I dont have to use the svn add & svn delete commands (as i dont have a list of the files being addedd/removed so cant do the add/delete).

Thanks for you help,

Answer (score 3):

If you can do it on Linux (or, presumably, CygWin), you can get that behaviour  like this:

```
svn status | grep '^!' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn rm
svn status | grep '^?' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add
svn commit
```